# Should I use JAXB now that I get warnings that it is deprecated?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am thinking about introducing some xml serialization/deserialization library for 20 year old code which uses string appending to construct xml documents. I would like to stick to JAXB api if possible. But I get deprecated warnings in Eclipse and if I am not wrong it has been removed in Java 9. The question then is, is it gone like, poof!!! ?

That seems unlikely seeing how widely xml is used. Or is it gone because jdk has an alternative for it ? If it hasn't disappeared completely how does one use JAXB and be future proof.

I am on jdk 1.8.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574426/how-to-resolve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception-in-j

Comment: Check out the accepted answer of the above SO post.

Comment: As JSON is pervasively used, you might consider Jackson, which supports XML as a serialization format.

Comment: Downstream expects it to be xml. So can't switch over.